# I have a function that has an offset parameter and want to loop over

Tags: python, while-loop, offset, mailchimp

I am using a function, clientmailchimp.lists.members.all, that returns a list of dictionaries for up to 1000 members (the function has an offset parameter which is 0 by default). After getting this dictionary, I want the ID value on my subscribedmembersid list.

```
subscribedmembers = clientmailchimp.lists.members.all(count=1000 )   
subscribedmembersid = [id['id'] for id in subscribedmembers['members']]
```

For results <1000 this function works, but when the returned value is >1000 I would have to use the offset parameter offset=1000 to get the second chunk of the list. How can I do this with a While loop that appends the chunks on an empty list?

I tried something like this but not sure im doing the loop correctly

```
subscribedmemberslist = []
offset = 0

while len(subscribedmembersid) > 1000 :
    subscribedmembers = clientmailchimp.lists.members.all(count=1000, offset=offset)
    subscribedmembersid = [id['id'] for id in subscribedmembers['members']]
    offset =+ 1000
    subscribedmemberslist.append(subscribedmembersid)
```

I just expect a list of all the members all together.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `get_all` parameter to `True` will ignore the `offset` and `count` parameters and return the complete set of members without need for looping trough the members and make a new request each time.

e.g. `client.lists.members.all(list_id='', get_all=True)`

You could also make your own pagination method, but you'll need to find out the total number of members to determine the number of pages you could get with provided count (e.g. if there are 5000 members, with count 1000 you will have 5 pages, and you just move the offset by 1000)